# Uses for setInterval that cannot be achieved using setTimeout or RAF?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am struggling to think of a use case in web-application development that needs to use `setInterval`.

The "danger" with `setInterval` being that it just queues up callbacks should one not complete within the allocated interval.

Furthermore, the behaviour of `setInterval` can be simulated with `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` without this "danger".

Given this, can someone provide me with a use-case where `setInterval` is the superior/more appropriate option?

**Edit:**

Thought I'd jot down my findings.

`setInterval` is an easy way to have something run at even-ish intervals. The intervals will mainly be quite accurate, but if the event loop is blocked, then they might be completely inaccurate.

```js
var x = 0;
setInterval(function() { 
   waitBlocking(5000);
   document.write(x++);
},100);

function waitBlocking(ms) {
    var start = Date.now();
    while((Date.now() - start) < ms) {}
}
```

As far as I can tell, `setInterval` is useful not if you want evenly spread interval callback invocations (see above), but if you want a convenient way of having a specific number of callback invocations in a period, spread across the timeframe as close as possible to when they should have run. Which seems like a rather narrow use case.

I'm sure I am missing something.

**Edit 2:**

This is basically the best approximation of a clock JS can achieve, so I guess `setInterval` is the "clock timer". Presumably this was useful in applications that needed simple clocks.

Comment: I would disagree that that functionality is a "danger" of `setInterval`; it is a specific feature, and is useful in situations where you want your callbacks to execute on a specific schedule that is independent of how long the callback takes to execute.

Comment: Being single threaded, it is not independent, but I take your point.

Comment: "being that it just queues up callbacks should one not complete within the allocated interval." --- that's not entirely true. Only up to one extra call is queued. The benefit of `setInterval` is that you don't need to manage the next call manually (otherwise you spoil your domain-specific code with setting up `setTimeout`). Not to say that not always it is an anonymous function that you can easily hack but a reference to a function from a variable.

Comment: Please can you supply the reference for "upto one extra call is queued". This is the observed behavior, but I couldn't tease it out of https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-setinterval

Comment: @BenAston "Each object that implements the WindowTimers interface has a list of active timeouts and a list of active intervals. Each entry in these lists is identified by a number, which must be unique within its list for the lifetime of the object that implements the WindowTimers interface."

Comment: `setInterval` returns a unique ID to use with `clearInterval` later. `requestAnimationFrame` and `setTimeout` also return unique IDs, but a different one for each call - something you need to handle if you call them recursively.

Answer (score 1):

The use-case where `setTnterval` is appropriate is when you want to execute a function at an exact time. `setInterval` and `setTimeout` has subtitle differences. `setInterval` execute it function after delay starting from the time when the previose `setInterval` fired. 
`setInterval` is also not reclusive so there is no fear of closures and memory leaks. More details can however be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Below is the code for a typical `setInterval` function

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 500);

function myCallback() {
  // Your code here
}
```

Where as to achieve the same function using setTimeout you will have to create a recursion which can create closures and then the problem of memory leaks comes in as demonstrated below.

```
function startTimer() {   
    var count = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
    setTimeout(function() {
        //do some stuff
        count.push(100);//you have just create a closure 
        //and all the problems that is associated with it
        startTimer();//this is where the recursion happens 
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same answer, but then I looked Ben's profile, he has 11k reputation, he is a Javascript consultant, he wrote many javascript articles on Medium and realized that probably he is looking for a more pragmatic answer :) Wait! What? I'm not a stalker...

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip let me include some codes to better illustrate my answer